# Decidability of given languages

Tags: computer-science, computational-complexity, computability

Given are the following languages:

$L_1 = \{0\}\\
L_2 = \{w \in \{0,1\}^{*} | L(M_w) = \{0\}\}\\
L_3 = \{w \in \{0,1\}^{*} | M_w \text{ stops at all entries }\} \\
L_4 =  \{w \in \{0,1\}^{*} | L((0|1)^{*}0) \cap\ L(M_w) = \emptyset \}
$

(Whereas $M_w$ describes the turing machine with coding $w$.)

Now I want to decide whether these languages are decidable, undecidable or semi-decidable. My intuitions are the following:

1. is decidable, since its a finite set.
2. is undecidable. Proof: Rice's theorem with f as the zero map.
3. is undecidable. Proof: Reduction from the halting problem on the empty tape.
4. probably also undecidable, but I have not idea how to proof it.

Can you tell me whether these assumptions are right and how I could proof number 4? Thank you!

Comment: Dear eva, what are $M_w$ and $L(M_w)$?

Comment: Oh sorry, these are the normal definitions for turing machines from our course. I will correct my post - thank you!

Comment: And what is $f$ in your Rice's theorem ?

Comment: You now how for Rice's theorem you have a set $F \subset P$ and a computable function $f$ and you want to show that $f \in F$? Its kinda hard to explain, in German (my native language) the Rice's theorem is also explained a little different than the one on English wikipedia, which makes it even harder to translate my thoughts ;) I have a different idea on how to proof number 2, though. The important question for me is to get an idea on how to solve 4.

Comment: When I teach the Rice's theorem, I usually explain it as : if a set S is defined by $\{w\;|\;\phi(M_w)\}$, where $\phi$ is any formula then either $S$ is trivial (empty or all) or $S\ge_m K$ (with $\ge_m$ the many one reduction and $K$ the halting set). So $L_2$, $L_3$ and $L_4$ all applies, it easy to see they are not trivial, so they are not decidable directly by Rice's theorem.

Comment: Alright, that makes sense - thank you!